# Unity Facebook API - FB.API() Syntax

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

(Using Unity 5.2.2, Unity Facebook SDK 7.2.2)

I am trying to grab my Facebook profile picture once I am logged in, make it into a `Sprite` and setting it as an `Image`. The method FBLogin() is called when a `Button` is clicked..

```
public void FBLogin()
{
    perms = new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" };
    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
}

private void AuthCallback(ILoginResult result)
{
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {                
        //Get Facebook Details
        getUserInfoFromFacebook();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
    }
}

private void getUserInfoFromFacebook()
{
    FB.API("/v2.5/me?fields=id,name,picture", Facebook.Unity.HttpMethod.GET, DealWithProfilePicture);
}

private void DealWithProfilePicture(IGraphResult result)
{
    if (result.Error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Problem with getting profile picture");
        FB.API("/v2.5/me?fields=id,name,picture",Facebook.Unity.HttpMethod.GET, DealWithProfilePicture);
        Debug.Log(result.Error);
        return;

    }

    profile_picture.sprite = Sprite.Create(result.Texture, new Rect(0,0,128,128), new Vector2(0,0));

}
```

I can't get the hang of the API syntax at all - it produces the error `400 Bad Request`. Can somebody help me out with the syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Sorry what type of object is profile_picture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in that [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user) that the picture is not a field of the user, but an extra edge, which can be retrieved by requesting [`/me/picture`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/):

```
FB.API("/me/picture",HttpMethod.GET,delegate(IGraphResult result) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
    {
        Debug.Log("received texture with resolution "+result.Texture.width + "x" + result.Texture.height);
        profile_picture.sprite = Sprite.Create(result.Texture, new Rect(0,0,128,128), new Vector2(0,0));
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("received error="+result.Error);
    }
});
```

Comment: `/me/picture` worked instead of `/me?fields=id,name,picture` - Thanks.